# How can any patch-set commit message of Gerrit change

Tags: gerrit

I'm trying to get the commit message of specific patch-set of Gerrit change.
The patch-set is not the latest one.

I tried:

```
ssh our-gerrit-server gerrit query --format=JSON  --commit-message  commit:c895abd810d3880729dfdf4a58462aa81cee38a1
```

But, could get only the commit message of the current patch-set
I also tried:

```
ssh git-amr-1 gerrit query --format=JSON  --commit-message --patch-sets commit:c895abd810d3880729dfdf4a58462aa81cee38a1
```

Now, I have got fields of all of the patch sets. But the commit message is of the current-patch-set.
Any idea?

Comment: What's the point of rewriting history, in this case, please (even if you've written your password in the commit-message)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use REST with something like this:

```
curl -s --request GET --user USER "https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/?q=COMMIT&o=ALL_REVISIONS&o=ALL_COMMITS"
```

Or using CHANGE-NUMBER and the PATCHSET-NUMBER

```
curl -s --request GET --user USER https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER/revisions/PATCHSET-NUMBER/commit
```

See more options [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#change-endpoints).